# Idea Intellij unboxing warning does not seem to be based on data flow analysis

Tags: java, intellij-idea, iteration, compiler-warnings, dataflow

There are multiple questions on SO about NullPointerException arising from unboxing, especially when doing something like `int k = ...` from an `Integer` object. I understand that issue. My question is about data flow analysis:

The squiggly yellow line appears when I do the following:

```
HashBiMap<String, Integer> myMap = ... ; // some method populates a Guava HashBiMap
for (String s : myMap.keySet()) {
    int i = myMap.get(s); // Intellij issues warning here about NullPointerException
}
```

The warning says that based on data flow analysis, Intellij thinks that a NullPointerException may be thrown at runtime. The warning, however, goes away when I change the above code to iterate as follows:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    String s = entry.getKey();
    int i = entry.getValue(); 
}
```

As far as I can see, both iterations have the same data flow and neither should issue any warning (or both should issue the same warning). What, if any, is the difference in the data flows of the two ways of iterating over a map?

Comment: The map can return null if there is no value for the key, null can not convert to int... NPE is thrown.

Comment: The inspections are probably based on external annotations created by JetBrains.  Maybe they document the result of `Map.get()` as nullable, and `Map.Entry.getValue()` as non-nullable?

Comment: Ah, yes, that is possible! I wasn't sure if I was missing something obvious. I will wait for a more certain answer, though, before blaming the yellow squiggly line on my favorite IDE.

Comment: @ChthonicProject, It should warn for both pieces of code... `HashBiMap` allows `null` for values, so the `EntrySet` can also return `null`.  Guaranteeing that the `Map` will never contain null values is well beyond the scope of IDE code analysis... you need a programmer for that!

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Which is why I was expecting either (a) both codes issue warning, or (b) neither issue warning. I suppose Mike's answer is the best possible explanation here, unless and until someone can for (or against) it.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I can see, both iterations have the same data flow and neither should issue any warning. What, if any, is the difference in the data flows of the two ways of iterating over a map?

I believe the difference is that the iterator on `entrySet()` is assumed (by DFA, annotations, or just explicitly) to return only complete entries, i.e., key-value pairs where the value is never `null`.  Iterating over `keySet()` and pulling the values out separately is a bit different.  Consider a concurrent map: the value could be removed after the key is retrieved, but before the call to `get()`.

That assumption doesn't seem to hold up in your case, though, as the documentation for `HashBiMap` indicates that both `null` keys and values are supported.

Comment: +1 for using the concurrent scenario. Hadn't thought of that at all.

Comment: The iterator on `entrySet()` returns only complete entries, which can contain any value for an `Integer`, including `null`.